# Triggering server message to client on socket from HTTP request

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, iot

I have a server that handles all the TCP connection for IoT devices. My IoT devices do actuation on the basis of command send by server over TCP connection. Now I want to trigger those command using my mobile app or web app. Should i connect my app also over socket or go with http request, if http then how internally it can trigger the command from server to client.
Also i want to scale it such that it can handle millions devices hence some load balancer will also come into picture.

Comment: How is your server code implemented?

Comment: I have implemented in nodejs where i am saving the session information in an array for each client connection. The problem is I am finding problem in scaling as server is crashing as the no of devices increases.

Comment: Do not use Session, rather go for something like redis

Comment: You might want to consider using a Publish/Subscribe architecture using a protocol like MQTT or CoAP.  MQTT is very well supported in Node.JS and if your application needs to trigger multiple devices at once, the server would just publish one MQTT message that all the clients would receive and active. This would just require an MQTT Broker, to which both clients and server to connect to for passing messages.